# Help with complex mixed model: random terms specification

Tags: mixed-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset comprised of repeated measures of 200 individuals. 
Response variable is "**trait**"
Individuals come from two different "**areas**": area A and area B
In each area, individuals were captured in different places, so capture "**location**" has 5 levels in area A, and 5 levels in area B.
Individuals were assesed multiple and consecutive times, once per month, but not at the same time. This is, the study period is three years but within it, each ID was monitored during a shorter period (mean=10 months, this is 10 replicates). So "**year**" has to be accounted for as well.
I have the "**size**" of each individual as well.
Finally, the response trait varies over the year, so there is one variable that account for that variability, in this case it is called "**month**".

A very simple model to start with would be this one:

a) trait~size+location+area+year+month+(1|ID)

But of course if I want to investigate individual variation in the response trait over the year I need a random slope model:

b) trait~size+location+area+year+month+(month|ID)

However, I'm not sure whether area and location should be considered random effects (each ID comes from only one location inside one area). In this case, should they be two different additional random effects, and should ID be nested in them (and in this case, nested separately in area and location, or nested in location which in turn is nested in area). Some models that came to my mind:

c) trait~size+year+month+(month|ID)+(1|location/area)

d) trait~size+year+month+(month|ID)+(1|ID/location/area) (is this possible?)

e) trait~size+year+month+(month|ID)+(1|location) +(1|area)

f) trait~size+year+month+(month|ID)+(1|ID/location) +(1|ID/area)

What would be the most logical model? Also, I'm leaving year as a fixed effect, which I guess could also be a random effect. Is that ok?

**Edit**: I´m not assuming a linear relationship between the response trait and month, but rather an annual cycle. For this, I have considered to enter month as a polynomial, something like poly(month,3), so it can described an annual cycle. Other option would be to enter it as a factor of 12 levels, but in that case could I still specify the month|ID random factor?

Thanks!